# Improper integral $\int \limits_{2}^{4}\frac{\sqrt{(16 - x^2)^5}}{(x^2 - 9x + 20)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I can't figure out how to solve (say whether it converges or diverges) the following improper integral:
$$
\int \limits_{2}^{4}\frac{\sqrt{(16 - x^2)^5}}{(x^2 - 9x + 20)^3}dx
$$
I've tried to simplify this and got:
$$
\int \limits_{2}^{4}\frac{(4 + x)^{5/2}}{(4 - x)^{1/2}(5 - x)^3}
$$
But I don't know what to do next. Could you please give me some hint

Comment: have you proved that your integral converges?

Comment: Check the powers after your 'simplification'.

Comment: @dr-sonnhard-graubner, no. This is thing I have to prove or disproof, but don't know how.

Comment: @simply-beautiful-art, I believe now it's correct...

Comment: The problematic term in the integrand is $\sqrt{4-x}$ in the denominator.  Can you show that the integrand is bounded by a multiple of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x}}$, then relate to the $p$-integral $\int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$?

Comment: i got this result $$36 \sqrt{3}+\frac{125 \pi }{3}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of any other suggestions, here is an outline of how you can evaluate this by fairly straightforward means:

Firstly, from where you left off, you can do the substitution $x=4\cos 2\theta$ and obtain

$$1024\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\cos^6\theta}{(5-4\cos2\theta)^3}d\theta$$

Then a further substitution of $t=\tan\theta$ leads to $$1024\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{1}{(1+t^2)(1+9t^2)^3}dt$$

The integrand is then expressed in partial fractions, so we end up having to evaluate $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{18}{1+9t^2}-\frac{144}{(1+9t^2)^2}+\frac{1152}{(1+9t^2)^3}-\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

And indeed the final answer is $36\sqrt{3}+\frac{125\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

An alternate substitution is $x = 4 \, \sin(t)$ which leads to, with some difficulty,
\begin{align}
\int \frac{(16 - x^2)^{5/2}}{(x^2 - 9 x + 20)^3} \, dx = \frac{81}{2} \, \frac{x-6}{(x-5)^2} \, \sqrt{16 - x^2} - 63 \, \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{16 - 5x}{3 \, \sqrt{16 - x^2}}\right) - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) + c_{0}. 
\end{align}
Evaluating the integral at the limits (2,4) then provides the integrals value:
\begin{align}
\int_{2}^{4} \frac{(16 - x^2)^{5/2}}{(x^2 - 9 x + 20)^3} \, dx = 36 \, \sqrt{3} + \frac{125 \, \pi}{3}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

A systematic evaluation: Rewrite the integral with $x=y-5$

$$I=\int_{2}^{4}\frac{\sqrt{(16 - x^2)^5}}{(x^2 - 9x + 20)^3}dx= \int_{1}^{3}\left(\frac9y-1\right)^3\frac{1}{\sqrt{(9-y)(y-1)}}dy
$$
and then apply the reduction formula below for $I_n =\int_1^3 \frac{dy}{y^n \sqrt{(9-y)(y-1)}}$
$$9(n-1)I_n = \frac{2\sqrt3}{3^{n-1}}+5(2n-3)I_{n-1}-(n-2)I_{n-2}
$$
to reduce the integral
\begin{align}
I=&\ 36\sqrt3  +189I_1 - I_0\\
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
I_1 =& \int_1^3 \frac{1}{y\sqrt{(9-y)(y-1)}}dy
=\frac13\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac53x-3}{\sqrt{(9-y)(y-1)}}\bigg|_1^3 =\frac{2\pi}9\\
 I_0 =& \int_1^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(9-y)(y-1)}}dy
=\tan^{-1}\frac{x-5}{\sqrt{(9-y)(y-1)}}\bigg|_1^3 =\frac{\pi}3
\end{align}
Thus
$$I= 36\sqrt3 +189\cdot\frac{2\pi}9-\frac\pi3= 36\sqrt3 +\frac{125\pi}3
$$

Answer (score 0):

With the Euler substitution

$$t = \frac{\sqrt{16-x^2}-4}x \implies x = -\frac{8t}{1+t^2} \implies dx = -8\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt \tag{$\star$}$$

we have

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{2}^{4} \frac{\sqrt{(16 - x^2)^5}}{(x^2 - 9x + 20)^3} \,dx \\
&= \int_2^4 \frac{(x+4)^2 \sqrt{16-x^2}}{(x-4) (x-5)^3} \, dx \\
&= -8 \int_{\sqrt3-2}^{-1} \frac{\left(-\frac{8t}{1+t^2}+4\right)^2 \left(-\frac{8t^2}{1+t^2}+4\right)}{\left(-\frac{8t}{1+t^2}-4\right) \left(-\frac{8t}{1+t^2}-5\right)^3} \, \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} \, dt \tag{$\star$} \\
&= 128 \int_{-1}^{\sqrt3-2} \frac{(1-t)^6}{\left(5t^2+8t+5\right)^3(1+t^2)} \, dt
\end{align*}$$

and we can proceed with partial fractions (though it's a bit messy).